# Refreshing web page when disabling javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

In firefox when user clicks the disable javascript in developer tools the page refreshes, but in chrome it does not.

Is there any way to refresh the page on chrome?

Comment: Refresh the page in chrome ? mean you want jquery code for it ? did you tried $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: That is not related with jquery or js ,but chrome browser !

Comment: is there any way i can get browser events such as when user clicks an option such as disable javascript using js

Comment: Its not clear enough, you want to disable javascript using js code ? which works in chrome ?

Comment: technically impossible, since the user disables JS, so i guess its a FF feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0"></noscript>
```

For more details about META tag: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: Thanks , but can i invoke this script when user disables the javascript in browser when the page is already reloaded

Comment: Hm...interesting thing. On test page with this line of code disabling JS has no effect, but enabling it stops cycle reloading.

Comment: ...probably, you need some event to write appropriate handler.